# Where does "Voice Recorder" save files to on Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: samsung, file-management, samsung-voice-recorder

I don't seem to find the recorded files on my Samsung Galaxy S6. What is the file path to the saved recording files? Google doesn't tell me the answer.

Comment: Does it not show the recorded files inside it?

Comment: @beeshyams no sounds folder.

Comment: @Firelord but i can't copy it directly to my computer.

Comment: Checked with a friend who has s6 edge and may help you locate. You can see the file from your Tools>My files>audio> [file_name].m4a. By clicking it he can share it by various means. Path is /storage/emulated/0/voice recorder. Can you check please?

Comment: @beeshyams Like I said I found nothing.

Comment: Suggest you contact Samsung support in your area

Comment: @beeshyams they didn't reply. I asked the question in August.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say with absolute certainty where they are on a Samsung S6, but on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3, and I doubt that they change their filesystem layout too much from one device to the next.

I can see them from Windows 10 at:

```
This PC\SM-N900T\Phone\Sounds\Voice 001.m4a
This PC\SM-N900T\Phone\Sounds\Voice 002.m4a
This PC\SM-N900T\Phone\Sounds\Voice 003.m4a
This PC\SM-N900T\Phone\Sounds\Voice . . .
```

Obviously the mount point will have a different name through other operating systems, but the path from the mount point will be the same.

As viewed from within the phone itself, they're at:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Sounds/Voice . . .
```

If Samsung changes things between devices, well, shame on them. Then this won't help you, but it will at least help people with the same layout as the Galaxy 3.

I found it by searching from within ES File Explorer, and checked for similar names through the Windows mount point. So if it's not in the same place, you can at least search for it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This was the path I ended up finding using a local search. I didn't change it so this must be the default path for the Samsung Voice Recorder
\Samsung Galaxy Note 5\Phone\Call

Answer (score 0):

Recordings can be found under: settings/device maintenance/memory or storage.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the Phone. Then click in the "Voice Recorder" folder. The files were there for me.

Comment: Check your SD card.  Voice Recorder puts it on the SD card if able.  Notably, things already on the SD card won't appear in VR's collection necessarily.

Answer (score -2):

On my S8+ it is in Phone/Recorders